# How to add Open eVision library to a project in Microsoft Visual Studio for a C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to run a sample C++ project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. The sample file is generated using Open eVision Studio

```
// This cpp script file was created by Open eVision Studio.
// Open eVision Studio (c)Euresys s.a. Belgium 2006.
// Date : 9/3/2020 at 10:37.

// This section contains the variable declarations

#include "Open_eVision_2_10.h"
using namespace Euresys::Open_eVision_2_10;

using namespace std;
EImageBW8 EBW8Image1; // EImageBW8 instance
EImageBW8 EBW8Image2; // EImageBW8 instance
EImageBW8 EBW8Image3; // EImageBW8 instance


// This section contains the operations code

try {
    EBW8Image1.Load("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Euresys\\Open eVision 2.10\\Sample Images\\EasyMatch\\Switch1.tif");
    EBW8Image2.Load("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Euresys\\Open eVision 2.10\\Sample Images\\EasyMatch\\Switch1.tif");
    EBW8Image3.SetSize(512, 512);
    // Make image black
    EasyImage::Oper(EArithmeticLogicOperation_Copy, EBW8(0), &EBW8Image3);
    EasyImage::Threshold(&EBW8Image2, &EBW8Image3, 85);
    EasyImage::Threshold(&EBW8Image2, &EBW8Image3, 126);
    EasyImage::Threshold(&EBW8Image2, &EBW8Image3, 139);
}
catch(const EException&){
   // Insert exception handling code here
}
```

What I am trying to do is to run this in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. I have created a `C++ Desktop application` and copy pasted the above code. In the project properties  C/C++ -> General -> Additional include directories as `C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Euresys\Open eVision 2.10\Include;`
But error during build. Some of the error displayed.

```
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "Open_eVision_2_10.h"   euresys_1   


Error (active)  E0276   name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name euresys_1   


Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'Open_eVision_2_10.h': No such file or directory  euresys_1   

Error (active)  E0020   identifier "EImageBW8" is undefined euresys_1
```

The screen shot 
[image]

Comment: Does the bottom part of the additional include directories dialog show the correct path?

Comment: @AlanBirtles This is the path to euresys open evision lib: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Euresys\Open eVision 2.10\Include`

Comment: And does the additional include directories dialog show this path?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes.

Comment: Replace `%28x86%29` with just `(x86)`

Comment: @AlanBirtles tried replacing `` with `(x86)`. But again the same error. The project type was `C++ Desktop application`. I tried to change platform from `x86` to `x64`, then most of the errors disappeared. But error occured `Error C1128 number of sections exceeded object file format limit: compile with /bigob`. Do we need to put the `try{} catch{}` inside a `main()`?

Comment: no, you need to enable the bigobj option as stated in the error message

Comment: @AlanBirtles Found out the issue. First thing is that the Euresys Open eVision library needs license activation to work properly. Also the supported MS Visual Studio version is  2017 and below.